# Pandas, selecting a range of rows based on a date and time column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tkinter

I am trying to make a dataframe in python with pandas, that selects a range of rows based on a two values of time the user selects.

Here is the code...

```
df = pd.read_csv('Dataset/20200118/310/summary.csv', index_col=0)
del df['Timezone (minutes)']
del df['Unix Timestamp (UTC)']

        df_subset = df[("Datetime (UTC)" >= value_inside_start.get()) & ("Datetime (UTC)" <= value_inside_end.get())]
        print(df_subset)

        value_inside_start = StringVar(frame_left)
        value_inside_end = StringVar(frame_left)
        value_inside_start.set(Date[0])
        value_inside_end.set(Date[20])
        drop = OptionMenu(frame_left, value_inside_start, *Date)
        drop.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="NEW")
        drop2 = OptionMenu(frame_left, value_inside_end, *Date)
        drop2.grid(row=3, column=0, pady=1, sticky="NEW")
```

There is a lot of code left out because it is such a big project so if you need to see more just ask...

Here in the code I create a subset dataframe that receives two variables, value_inside_start and value_inside_end and compares that to a column in in the original dataframe. Am I looking at this the correct way?

Here is the original dataframe if you need to see that...

```
                      Acc magnitude avg   Eda avg   Temp avg  \
Datetime (UTC)                                                 
2020-01-17T23:48:00Z           1.063262  0.541921  30.155257   
2020-01-17T23:49:00Z           1.005967  0.539037  29.979900   
2020-01-17T23:50:00Z           1.045804  0.535254  29.713417   
2020-01-17T23:51:00Z           1.017389  0.532977  29.416833   
2020-01-17T23:52:00Z           1.030430  0.532688  29.275200
```

The only error I get is KeyError: False

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\e077637\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\e077637\Documents\Python_Data_App\main.py", line 125, in plot
    df_subset = df[("Datetime (UTC)" >= value_inside_start.get()) & ("Datetime (UTC)" <= value_inside_end.get())]
                ~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\e077637\Documents\Python_Data_App\venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3761, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\e077637\Documents\Python_Data_App\venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3655, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: False
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that you're not actually doing the subsetting properly. When you pass:

```
("Datetime (UTC)" >= value_inside_start.get()) & ("Datetime (UTC)" <= value_inside_end.get())
```

You're actually doing the following:

1. Is the string `Datetime (UTC)` greater than equal to `value_inside_start.get()`?
2. Is the string `Datetime (UTC)` less than or equal to `value_inside_end.get()`?
3. Return a boolean value `True` if [1] and [2] are both `True`

What's returned is `False`. `False` is a boolean value. It is not the name of a column in your data frame. Thus, the data frame throws `KeyError`.

---

I am greatly unclear as to what you're trying to do in your code. I don't know what `value_inside_start.get()` returns.

But if you are trying merely to subset to *rows* which have a date between two other known dates, just use:

```
df[df['date'].between(start, end)]
```

Technically, this operates with strings Where `start` and `end` are both strings but you should force all your variables into time formats. Do this by passing `parse_dates=['name of your column here']` in `pd.read_csv` and getting `start` and `end` as `pd.Timestamp` values.

If you need to do it on a per-row basis, ie the dates are different for each possible row combination, then merge through and then something like `df.query('begin <= date <= end')`.